# 23.04: Sound issues with wired headphones

Tags: sound, 23.04, pipewire, dell-vostro

I've been having some audio issues after updating to Ubuntu 23.04. I have a Dell Vostro 3405.

So...internal speakers work fine. When I plug in my headphones (wired) sound works fine. However, if I need to step out for a moment and the screen turns off, or I close the lid of my laptop, when I log back in sound stops working in both the headphones and the speakers. After rebooting the issue is solved, but I'm getting fed up with having to reboot every time this happens, as it interrupts my work.

Note: Bluetooth headphones work just fine. But I have wired ones at work.

I've been trying to find a solution, and I've noticed some people having similar issues, but not THE SAME issue I'm having.

I tried doing the "sudo alsactl restore" command but it did not work.

Here's the inxi output for the audio devices:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_pci_acp3x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-26-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

I appreciate any guidance you can give me with this, I'm a little lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've Sound Blaster Z, and sometimes sound not even come through, & sometimes it sounds like destroyed speaker, Very poor suuprt for dedicated sound cards on Ubuntu.